# extract item from list in R using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a list in R from a Structural VAR Model I've run. Here is the dataset I've used

```
structure(c(-2.46773175636719, -7.72826473957142, 11.7280053716074, 
-1.90017613519231, 2.46070753200911, -10.9055849254775, 12.5325444143789, 
1.3401777880631, 1.11706357603545, -11.9683333308867, 13.8014223673123, 
3.00567366940339, 1.93467425287253, -12.4811258520841, 12.5337510851622, 
6.17970387794458, -0.311524449552714, -4.43067381564184, 6.00580266302142, 
0.733215859597713, -0.0920826461465296, -10.4968848655989, 15.1592141225619, 
-0.0142294828419764, 2.81612947228318, -7.95484787976672, 11.3258100085652, 
-4.26536944046738, 1.71777230300645, 3.05071906367438, 6.86888493397788, 
-2.04121390648186, -5.45632423113958, 4.32701496742318, -1.77039007913358, 
-3.38387552001187, -3.6948032720689, 9.71137617961375, 7.70239243534423, 
-7.34908250395865, 1.66529724744393, 4.12699586248877, 1.46757481960265, 
0.371903496562886, -3.1265641490501, 10.1504446414976, -6.97113134346488, 
10.6335568680931, -7.74296970668011, -0.31563625249369, 4.86848083529221, 
0.0394209612387897, 4.1060141554107, 4.40828962229318, -3.65631265465627, 
-0.804371886780864, 5.300399767623, 3.33547294572138, 2.19966779280814, 
-2.96620054964727, 2.01147630916658, 3.00808531323007, -1.78858517036105, 
-0.262917554632125, -2.63540419004151, 3.42060573075127, -0.379197105963414, 
-2.24861964821645, -1.33132752566709, 1.67672890048411, 2.42834777679839, 
-1.28230298674303, 2.33228006495114, -1.79196678955762, -3.25533945043563, 
-2.49506277883942, 3.87275419034108, -0.237088301198796, 3.15158720918571, 
-8.16796902280537, -5.40342750457601, -0.684253285161596, 2.76776077124627, 
3.03762540403962, 1.59655060303945, 2.81108799665279, 2.12619249528281, 
1.25976266808472, 1.75072385830202, 3.35523567403357, 3.66056933213099, 
2.81157744760496, 2.8694753969682, 1.22389693906415, 1.23949528512668, 
0.655297291930701, -0.0811557166513488, 2.49469766016768, 1.04750905161959, 
0.553154355370644, 0.0394037933455493, 0.495095459931427, 0.263970407073533, 
1.46876270708987, 1.02690822562028, 1.21249150827216, 0.744350196120713, 
2.28082505446663, 1.40375659950536, 1.59077468759525, 1.74048892256584, 
1.81791859189397, 0.640927792895951, 2.05320969806211, 3.31708856718933, 
3.94172305193239, 1.29907384513261, 2.18844272980503, 2.02564945461834, 
2.89662683480758, 0.531971587307556, 1.69103059033393, 0.195326999327161, 
1.20287931837835, -0.0417495586606087, 1.89055607207678, 1.8793164132429, 
1.19212718508228, 1.43097285231573, 2.4079363839828, 1.02287700043888, 
1.41700117422383, 1.9324642470476, 1.42192313279805, 1.00916357593048, 
1.26198292983659, 0.929701659038162, 1.77329986790085, 1.88793046797189, 
0.685737107435092, 0.400744609924519, 0.766302538581343, 1.09780031685389, 
1.00049427220021, 0.535284014354875, 3.18688973234602, 1.75770144393539, 
1.19538307882463, 0.904511107610428, 3.52708500618766, 0.526934426385495, 
0.361429093322574, 0.624469028588326, 1.95600784906818, 0.781933189336748, 
1.09121935535335, 1.30962848646536, 1.24173607356797, 0.453213216209214, 
0.468243562258674, 0.489076348335971, 0.848706378173603, 0.125371629239357, 
0.817153292286932), .Dim = c(82L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("GDP_NAM", "CPI_NAM")), index = structure(c(962323200, 
970272000, 978220800, 985996800, 993859200, 1001808000, 1009756800, 
1017532800, 1025395200, 1033344000, 1041292800, 1049068800, 1056931200, 
1064880000, 1072828800, 1080691200, 1088553600, 1096502400, 1104451200, 
1112227200, 1120089600, 1128038400, 1135987200, 1143763200, 1151625600, 
1159574400, 1167523200, 1175299200, 1183161600, 1191110400, 1199059200, 
1206921600, 1214784000, 1222732800, 1230681600, 1238457600, 1246320000, 
1254268800, 1262217600, 1269993600, 1277856000, 1285804800, 1293753600, 
1301529600, 1309392000, 1317340800, 1325289600, 1333152000, 1341014400, 
1348963200, 1356912000, 1364688000, 1372550400, 1380499200, 1388448000, 
1396224000, 1404086400, 1412035200, 1419984000, 1427760000, 1435622400, 
1443571200, 1451520000, 1459382400, 1467244800, 1475193600, 1483142400, 
1490918400, 1498780800, 1506729600, 1514678400, 1522454400, 1530316800, 
1538265600, 1546214400, 1553990400, 1561852800, 1569801600, 1577750400, 
1585612800, 1593475200, 1601424000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))
```

and the code I've used to create the model

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vars)

var.namibia <- namibia %>% VAR(.,p=1,type = 'both',season=NULL)
SVAR.namibia <- BQ(var.namibia)
```

from this, I want to extract residuals from the variables in my model. I can do it by indexing (see below), but I'm interested in finding a `dplyr` solution to achieve the same. Any suggestions?

```
res <- SVAR.namibia$var$varresult$CPI_NAM$residuals
```

Comment: Straight dplyr is about data frames and tibbles, not lists. Hence the good answer using purr below. If you changed your title to be "tidyverse" instead of "dplyr" the answer would literally be correct (right now it's not using dplyr so it isn't).   ... Also please make your example *minimal* ... you do not need all that data.

Comment: @Elin thanks, edited the title out and for future I'll post an extract of any datasets im using

Answer (score 3):

You can use `purrr`'s `pluck` function.

```
SVAR.namibia %>%
  purrr::pluck('var', 'varresult', 'CPI_NAM', 'residuals')
```

Comment: It would be great to add some explanation here.